# Is there a Javascript plugin or a method of selecting sections of a SVG or image?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm looking to build a system that maps injuries, and want to create a GUI whereby people can click on an SVG of the human body to select major body parts (head, arm, finger, legs, etc.). I've found an SVG but need to understand what the best way would be of selecting the underlying elements and passing to the DOM.

Is there a plugin available for this, or otherwise how should I approach it?

Comment: Use an svg element not an image. Group the svg paths and add `id`s (for example) to the groups you need to select. Select the group you need the same way you would select a DOM element.

Comment: Alternatively if you need to use an image you may use the [map and area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) HTML elements

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

1. Group parts of your SVG, using `<g>`
2. Give classes to parts of your SVG (either to `<g>` groups or to individual elements), such as:

   - `class="left forearm arms"`
   - `class= "right thigh legs"`
   - `class= "left ear head"`

That will give you the tools to select:

- the sides of the body (left or right)
- larger sections of the body (arms, legs, head etc.)
- smaller sections of the body (forearm, thigh, ear etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want more interactivity with svg, you can Load svg file with ajax and manipulate the elements (e.g: path, ellipse) with javascript. It's also possible to animate the elements with a library like Velocity Kute js or Anime js.

[Play with this example:](https://codepen.io/quadrochave/pen/xpzNJq) and try uncomment the line 18 or 21. This svg file is a bird with two elements: path and ellipse

```
// helper for select like jQuery
function $(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
};

svgpath = "https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg";
svgCanvas = $("#svgCanvas");

// Requisão Ajax para importar o svg
svgObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
svgObj.open("GET",svgpath ,false);
svgObj.overrideMimeType("image/svg+xml");
svgObj.send();
svgCanvas.appendChild(svgObj.responseXML.documentElement);


var bird = $("#bird");
//bird.style.display = "none";

var shadow = $("ellipse");
//shadow.style.display = "none";
```